# Do we have ansible module to perform resizing of openstack volumes?

Tags: openstack, ansible-module

Could you please let me know whether we can use ansible module os_volume for resizing of openstack volumes?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the latest version of the module supports increasing a volume's size.  It looks like you need to "create" the volume with its existing display name and a larger size.  Shrinking the volume is not supported.

(This is on what https://opendev.org/openstack/ansible-collections-openstack/src/branch/master/plugins/modules/volume.py says.  Note that `os_volume.py` symlinks to this file.)